# What is the limit to the number of tokens in Fogbugz?

Tags: fogbugz

Does Fogbugz restrict the user if everytime user uses new token to access api. If he continuously makes login attempts, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I am a FogBugz developer.

> "Does Fogbugz restrict the user if everytime user uses new token to access api. "

Nope.  If you can generate a new valid token, the API will accept it.

> "If he continuously makes login attempts, what happens?"

If those attempts succeed, then all is well.  You're welcome to generate zounds of tokens for yourself.

If those attempts fail, then you're welcome to try again, but FogBugz is smart enough to know when a brute-force attack is underway.  There is nothing special about the XML API login in comparison to the normal FogBugz login page aside from that it gives you back an XML API token.